# Safe way to use the result of getpwnam()/getpwuid()?

Tags: c, linux, getpwuid, getpwnam

I'm working on Linux and FreeBSD. When I use `getpwnam()` or `getpwuid()`, I get a pointer to a `passwd` struct. What's the safe way to use the `char*` members of that `passwd` struct?

The man page says this struct is a static object but will be overwritten by subsequent calls, so I guess the safe way is to use `strdup()` to get a copy of the `char*` members and then no longer uses the `passwd` struct.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The safest way is not to use them at all, but instead use `getpwnam_r` and `getpwuid_r`, which store the results in a caller-provided buffer. This not only avoids the issue you're asking about, but also makes your code safe for use in a multi-threaded process.